# Transparent Fixed-top Navbar with Boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-transparent">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Custom CSS (other than the base bootstrap CSS):

```css
.navbar-transparent {
    background:transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

I looked at other posts on Stack Overflow and here and there on Google, but I can't seem to find a way to make the navbar fully transparent.

So far it looks like this and surely there must be an easier way to set the navbar transparent than to have to edit for all the classes and sub classes and elements within those classes manually?

[image]

Comment: in your demo, it looks like the navbar IS transparent, except for the home button. But maybe I am not seeing it correctly. Try adding !important after the CSS commands and see if that has the desired effect.

Comment: It is, but I want the home button to be transparent too. Basically, I want the whole navbar to never have any background no matter what. I want it to only be text and text effects. I removed the background on home by adding:
`.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    background:transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}`

However, then I realised there's another issue. When it's responsive to mobile, it basically slides the menu over the content without a BG.

Comment: So now I'd need to add a separate rule to the media query to give it a background only when not in mobile view.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this works. If anyone has a better workaround, please answer.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 680px) {
.navbar-transparent {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to overwrite the ".active" class in your css.

You are already using that (predefined bootstrap) css-class in your code:

< li class="active">< a href="#">Home< / a >< / li>

try:

```
#navbar ul li.active {
    background:transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}

#navbar ul li:hover {        // to overwrite when you :hover the list items
    background:transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```